# How to hide paragraph and make visible with heading click using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about Javascript. I want to set some paragraphs on my page to hidden when the page loads, then have the paragraphs accessed by clicking on the heading. This is the html:

```
<div id="rightside">
    <div id="story1">
        <h3>Spice Girls premiere new song</h3>
        <p class="news"> 
            <em>Headlines (Friendship Never Ends)</em> 
            is the first new single from the reformed girl band since 2000 and is the official Children In Need track for 2007.
        </p>
        <p class="news">
            Geri Halliwell, Victoria Beckham, Melanie Brown, Melanie Chisholm and Emma Bunton have regrouped to promote a new Spice Girls' greatest hits album and an upcoming world tour.  <a href="#">more ...</a>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the Javascript I have that isn't working:

```
function hideElementByVisible('news'){
    document.getElementsByClassName('news').style.visibility = "none";
}

function showElementByDisplay('news',prop){
    if(prop == "block"){
        getElementsByClassName('news').style.display = "block";
    }
    else if(prop == "inline"){
        getElementsByClassName('news').style.display = "inline";
    }
}
window.onload=hideElementByVisible;
```

I'm getting an error saying that an identifier is expected in the first line of the Javascript but I can't think what that could be. Help please?

Comment: I know it's kind of late, but I added another answer with some suggestions for improving user2964055's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

$('#story1').find('p').hide().end().find('h3').click(function(){
$(this).next().slideToggle();});

$('#story2').find('p').hide().end().find('h3').click(function(){
$(this).next().slideToggle();});

$('#story3').find('p').hide().end().find('h3').click(function(){
$(this).next().slideToggle();});

$('#story4').find('p').hide().end().find('h3').click(function(){
$(this).next().slideToggle();});

});
```

Obviously with this the jquery.js file has to be attached to the document as well.

Answer (score 2):

As @Notulysses says, you're error (or one of them) is due to trying to set a style on a list of elements instead of the individual elements. However, I also want to recommend a different, more structured approach to achieving what you want.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67Xdu/1/) demonstrating the code below.

Try the following.

1. Put each story in it's own `<div class="story">` (the "story" class will allow you to access it easily in js).
2. In each story add the heading `<h3>Heading</h3>` and news `<p class="news">` (the "news" class will allow you to access it easily through js).
3. Finally use `addEventListener("click",...)` to toggle "hide" on a "news" class when a "story" is clicked.

### HTML

```
    <div id="rightside">
        <div class="story">
            <h3>Story 1</h3>
            <p class="news hide"> 
                <em>Headlines (Story 1!)</em> This is story1 news.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="story">
            <h3>Story 2</h3>
            <p class="news hide"> 
                <em>Headlines (Story 2!)</em> This is story2 news.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Javascript

```
    stories = document.getElementsByClassName('story');     
    for (var i = 0; i < stories.length; i++) {              // for each story
        stories[i].addEventListener("click", function () {  // add an onClick listener
            news = this.getElementsByClassName('news');     
            for (var j = 0; j < news.length; j++) {         // for each news in story
                news[j].classList.toggle('hide');           // toggle 'hide' on clicked
            }
        });
    }
```

### CSS

```
    .hide{
        display: none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@user2964055's had a great answer using JQuery, however I would suggest a couple things differently.

1. I would use **Classes instead of IDs** for the stories (unless the styling or actions of e.g. `#story1` is different from `#story2`). Using classes will allow you to remove the redundancy shown in @user2964055's answer by using a single `$('.story')` to set the style and action of all stories at once.
2. I would replace the `.find('p')`, `.find('h3')`, and `.next()` with queries that are less coupled with the choice and placement of HTML tags; e.g:

   - `.find('p')  => .find('.news')`
   - `.find('h3') => .find('.title')`
   - `.next()     => .sibling('.news')`

   This will allow you to change the tags (e.g. if title tag changes `h3` to `h2`) without affecting the javascript.

The following will find every `.story` class and toggle the visibility of the `.news` content when the `.title` is clicked ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7PpYn/1/)).

### HTML

```
<div id="rightside">
    <div class="story">                               <------- this is a story
        <h3 class="title"> Story 1 </h3>              <------- it includes a title
        <p  class="news"> This is story1 news. </p>   <------- and (sibling) news
    </div>

    <div class="story">                               <------- Add as many stories
        <h3 class="title"> Story 2 </h3>                       as you want
        <p  class="news"> This is story2 news. </p>  
    </div>                                                       
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('.story')                            // Filter: .stories
        .find('.news')                     // Filter: .stories .news
            .hide()                        // Hide all
            .end()                         // End current filter
        .find('.title')                    // Filter: .stories .title
            .click( function(){            // Set the onclick action
                $(this).siblings('.news')  // Filter: .stories .news (sibling of .title)
                .slideToggle();            // Toggle visibility
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('p').hide();      
    $('h4').click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
});
```